# Data tranfer from PowerApps to SharePoint does not work for every user

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

Kinda odd issue, I have here: At work we have a PowerApps tool to enter a row into a SharePoint list for each empty beer bottle collected. So you choose one of our brands, then some of its single products and by pressing the button, it saves a corresponing row into a SharePoint list (by use of the collect() function).
This is the case when I try it and how it should be, but a colleague, who has to use it mostly, does the same, steps, but in his case there is no new row created in the SP list.
We typically grant access to user groups in general and his group is granted access to this particular app. As an alternative, I also granted it to him personally, but still, no new rows are created.
It is especially strange, as he seems to have access to the app (otherwise he wouldn't be able to open it in the first place).

Hope, someone can provide some useful advice.

Comment: Is there a difference between the Sharepoint access group and the PowerApps group? Maybe the user is in the PowerApps group, but needs Sharepoint list access granted?

Comment: Hi SeaDude,

Yes, indeed. I found that out myself after I made this post. Took me a while to figure out, that SP needs to be granted seperately from PA.